# From Each According To Their Own

Tags: riddle, wordplay, steganography

I was amused to hear the following conversation between three of my acquaintances.

> **1:** What is it?
>   **2**: Look! That bird has got two beaks. Men! Walnuts for eyes every one!
>   **3:** Calm down, woman. That bird is always getting underfoot. Watch channel four. *Oblivion*’s on.
>   **1:** Cruise is a knockout!
>   **3:** And he certainly adorns all his passages.

I solved it. Can you?

**Hint**

> To find the answer, it helps to have some background information regarding my acquaintances which I have thoughtfully provided.
>
>  You're welcome.

**Another Hint**

> It also helps to use the title.

**Meta Hint On the First Hint**

> *What* information on the acquaintances?

**Meta Hint On the Other Hint**

> According to their own *what*?

Comment: Best. Hint. Ever.

Comment: With a hint that is as mind-bending as the actual riddle, all I can do is bookmark this to see how it is answered!

Comment: any other hints? this seems to be forgotten...

Comment: @thecoder16 Because you asked. :-)

Comment: With the hints, I thought it might have something to do with specific letters in the sentences (person 1, 1st letters, etc). The first one gives wii, which might point to the console, but the second line gives complete nonsense (ohiaoweeaoyvn to be precise)

Comment: @Fifth_H0r5eman Though this be madness, yet...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The answer to the riddle is...

> the word **deck**!

I got there by...

> using every word from speaker 1, every second word from speaker 2, and every third word from speaker 3 (carrying over the count between lines) to get this:
>
> > "What is it? That has two Men! for every woman. is underfoot. four. Cruise is a knockout! And adorns passages."
>
> But this can be rewritten by removing some punctuation, adding a few well placed commas, and changing some words a bit to the following:
>
> > "What is it that has two men for every woman, is underfoot for (a) cruise<sup>1</sup>, is a knockout, and adorns passages?"
>
> And the answer to each part is a **deck** of cards (a king and jack for every queen), a ships **deck**, to **deck** (punch) someone, and **deck** the halls!
>
>
>  <sup>1</sup>A better interpretation might be "underfoot for crews", i.e. crews on a ship.

Comment: Falalalala la la check mark!

Comment: (I was actually thinking of a play on the actor’s name but the answer is the same.)

Comment: @HughMeyers: Ahhh, I see the other meaning. I'll add it.

Comment: Absolutely! Congrats.

Answer (score 9):

From my own comment:

> Using every "one" word of speaker 1, every second word of 2, etc, we get:  What is it - that has two men for every - woman...  and then what seems to be gibberish.

For easy reading I'll put the remainder here:

> is underfoot four - Cruise is a knockout - certainly his

I'll add more to this if I can find a way to extend it to make more sense.

Comment: Yay! Progress on the steganography tag! How about the other two?

Comment: Well I think riddle is self evident :p Wordplay I always find takes more of a eureka moment...

Comment: *Almost* there with the steganography. Try another way on the last speech.

Comment: I'm thinking the last line is "And adorns passages", which makes more sense but doesn't quite fit with the method for the other lines.